# Full height on scroll position absolute nav issue

Tags: html, css

Ok, I saw several examples of similar issues but didn't seem to answer my specific current issue. All I'm trying to do, is have the side nav use 100% height. I've tried numerous tries with height, float, position, and yet it still seems to only fill the rendered viewport on load. How do I get it to reliably stretch the full height of all content? You'll see what I mean if you just scroll down in the example below.

> Example : [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzKwXJ)

I've tried some things like;

```
position:absolute;
left:0;top:0;bottom:0;
```

.

```
  float: left;
```

.

```
height: 100%
```

As I go through the process of kicking the dust off my web skills I occasionally get humbled like this. So if there's an exact duplicate I didn't find just let me know and I'll del this question. Thanks!

Comment: So for any future readers. If you're using sass/gulp, always check to make sure gulp is actually running watch before you waste frustration as to why nothing seems to work. In this instance, it froze and wasn't even watching. As soon as I reloaded it and built fresh it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a fixed?
I tried it and the nav bar grew.

Or if you could use 200% or 300% might fit what you need

Comment: Yes I did, but then I finally figured out that git bash had froze and gulp was apparently not watching the whole damn time......so once I reloaded gulp and built fresh, it was fine. Face palm moment indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the height of the page, and then set the nav to the height of the page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">

<script>

$(function(){

var height = $(window).height();
$("#nifty-sidenav").height(height+"px");

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:relative` to the parent. In this case:

```css
body {
   position:relative;
}
```